# hey there, looking out for a solution

Tags: javascript

Hi I am having trouble with getting my program to run properly. I was able to clear any syntax errors, but now I am having issue with my output.I need the output to be

```
* * * * *
* * * * 
* * *
* * 
*
```

Code is

```
var i = 1;
while (i < 6)
{
    if (i==1)
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "* * * * *<br>";
    }
    else if (i==2)
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "* * * *<br>";
    }
    else if (i==3)
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "* * *<br>" ;
    }
    else if (i==4)
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "* *<br>" ;
    }
    else if (i==5)
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "*" ;
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Not able to understand what is the problem in the code please ask a question clearly so as to we can solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

> Use `innerHTML += YOUR_VALUE` to insert new `HTML` in existing HTML

Try this:

```js
var i = 1;
while (i < 6) {
  if (i == 1) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "* * * * *<br>";
  } else if (i == 2) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += " * * * *<br>";
  } else if (i == 3) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += " * * *<br>";
  } else if (i == 4) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "* * <br>";
  } else if (i == 5) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "*<br>";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<br>";
  }
  i++;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/wxdkg9zz/)

**Or could be simplified like:**

```js
var i = 5;
var makeStart = function(count) {
  var star = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    star += '*';
  }
  return star;
}
while (i) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += makeStart(i) + '<br>';
  i--;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use loops instead.

```js
(function(){
  var html = "";
  for(var i = 5; i>0; i--){
    for(var j=0; j<i; j++){
      html+= "* ";
    }
    html += "<br/>";
  }
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= html;
})()
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```